# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable board[y][x]

Tags: python, typeerror

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable board[y][x]

Code:

```
    board = []
    bWidth = 10
    bHeight = 20
    for h in range(bHeight):
        row = []
        for w in range(bWidth):
            row.append(0)
        board.append(row)
    
    for y in range(bHeight):
            for x in range(bWidth):
                if board[y][x] == 0:
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\TUF\PycharmProjects\Tetris\main.py", line 92, in drawWindow
if board[y][x] == 0:
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Looks ok. Are you sure this is the exact code?

Comment: Is there anything between your two nested loops ? Cause this cause does work. Have your tried printing `board` just before entering the second part ?

Comment: I did try printing it before the second part does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it appears as though the code is missing something inside the second loop.
If i put a generic print statement there, it does get to the end and produces an array of zero's.

```py
board = []
bWidth = 10
bHeight = 20
for h in range(bHeight):
    row = []
    for w in range(bWidth):
        row.append(0)
    board.append(row)

for y in range(bHeight):
        for x in range(bWidth):
            if board[y][x] == 0:
                print('hello', x, y)  # <--- this or pass

board
```

gives this:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```